# I am trying to show an element on mouse over specific element

Tags: jquery, html

Here is jQuery function when I am using this function it is applying all div with class `.check` and I want to apply only hover div not all.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.pop').hover(function(){
            $('.check').animate({opacity: 'show'});
        }),
        $('.pop').mouseout(function(){
            $('.check').animate({opacity: 'hide'});
        })
    });
</script>
```

Here is html code of function #pop is parent and it's child .check

```
<div class="pop">
    <div class="check">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pop">
    <div class="check">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is css code

```
.pop {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:solid 1px green;
    position:relative;
}

.check {
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:none;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

When I am using this code jQuery function applying all. Check div and I want apply only one div. Check only on hover

Answer (score 2):

You are targeting all of them - you just need the one in the currently hovered container:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pop').mouseenter(function() {

        // I've thrown in stop() - see http://api.jquery.com/stop/
        $(this).find(".check").stop().animate({
            opacity: 'show'
        });
    });
    $('.pop').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find(".check").stop().animate({
            opacity: 'hide'
        });
    });
});​
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/WPhqG/3/)

p.s., I would favour this more concise approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pop').hover(function() {
        $(this).find(".check").fadeToggle()
    });
});​
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/WPhqG/2/)

Comment: Thanks bro you're code is working perfectly. I was very worry about this condition but you resolve it in seconds thank you very much again :)

Answer (score 1):

Try applying a context to the query for the check class

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.pop').hover(function(){
            $('.check', this).animate({opacity: 'show'});
        }),
        $('.pop').mouseout(function(){
            $('.check', this).animate({opacity: 'hide'});
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this:

```
$(".pop").hover(
function() {
    $(this).find(".check").animate({
        opacity: 'show'
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".check").animate({
        opacity: 'hide'
    });
});​
```